# App Store Submission Failing Because Of Icons

Tags: ios, app-store

I'm having trouble submitting an app to the app store.  It says that the icon files are not the right size.  It's telling me that the icon size is 0, which suggests to me it's not finding them.  I have all 3 icon files as per usual and I have them defined in the info.plist.

The really strange thing here is that the app is part of a framework that I built.  In that framework each app is a build target.  They all have the same icon files.  This will be the 4th app that's been submitted like this.  The previous 3 have submitted with no problem, so I have no idea why it suddenly can't use the icon files it's used 3 times before.

Has anybody run into anything like this?

Comment: When you finished archive, did you see any warnings?

Comment: None that I didn't see on the other apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes I just did.  There is an update to Application Loader that you need.

The fix is just to update Application Loader to 2.5.1:

https://itunesconnect.apple.com/apploader/ApplicationLoader_2.5.1.dmg

Comment: this is a bug when using Lion 10.7.3 and Xcode 4.2.1. You have two options: 1) upgrade to Xcode 4.3 2)build and archive your app using Xcode 4.2.1 and upload it using Application Loader 2.5.1

Comment: Just needed to upgrade Xcode.  Wasn't aware that my os had updated to 10.7.3

Answer (score 0):

Have you remove the icons and added them back to their location?  Delete the icons completely from your application run it without them, add them back and run it again.

Are the icons created or modified them from an Mac system? If the icons are created or modified them on a different system (Windows) and they are the correct iOS size 57px or 114px that will get reject but the iOS.

Just a thought!

Comment: Created on a mac.  And correct size.  They are the exact same icons that have gone through 3 times before.  I have deleted and added them back, but I haven't run the app with them deleted.  Will try that.